# нейронная сеть (keras) выводит только 100% ответ, как показать вероятности по каждому выходу?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Как мне сделать вывод предсказания в виде вероятностей:

```
import numpy
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# Задаем seed для повторяемости результатов
numpy.random.seed(42)

# Загружаем данные
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

X_train =  X_train[0:1000]
y_train =  y_train[0:1000]
# Размер мини-выборки
batch_size = 32
# Количество классов изображений
nb_classes = 10
# Количество эпох для обучения
nb_epoch = 5
# Размер изображений
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32

# Нормализуем данные
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# Преобразуем метки в категории
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

# Создаем последовательную модель
model = Sequential()
# Первый сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                        input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation='relu'))
# Второй сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
# Первый слой подвыборки
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Слой регуляризации Dropout
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# Третий сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Четвертый сверточный слой
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
# Второй слой подвыборки
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Слой регуляризации Dropout
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# Слой преобразования данных из 2D представления в плоское
model.add(Flatten())
# Полносвязный слой для классификации
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

# Слой регуляризации Dropout
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Выходной полносвязный слой
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Задаем параметры оптимизации
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Обучаем модель
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=nb_epoch,
              validation_split=0.1,
              shuffle=True,
              verbose=2)

# Оцениваем качество обучения модели на тестовых данных
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Точность работы на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Сейчас это вот так выводит:

```
1 - 0.0
2 - 0.0
3 - 0.0
4 - 0.0
5 - 100.0
6 - 0.0
7 - 0.0
8 - 0.0
9 - 0.0
10 - 0.0
['5 - deer']
```

А я хочу:

```
1 - 4.0
2 - 33.0
3 - 2.0
4 - 32.0
5 - 87.0
6 - 44.0
7 - 33.0
8 - 33.0
9 - 22.0
10- 22.0
['5 - deer']
```

Думал что это model.add(Dropout(0.5)) обрубает связи, но даже если все закомментировать, все равно выводит в 100% только 1н вариант.

Comment: по-моему основная проблема в том, что обучающая выборка слишком мала.  1000 изображений для данной задачи недостаточно

Comment: то я специально обрезал, что бы быстро тестировать.

Comment: еще подсказали -  Функцию активации softmax на последнем слое сети заменить на sigmoid.

Comment: если замените на сигмоид - получится ерунда... ;) Сигмоид используют для __бинарной__ классификации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример предсказаний после того как модель была обучена на *полной* обучающей выборке:

```
In [122]: test_sample = [100,200,300,400,500]

In [123]: Y_pred = model.predict(np.array(X_test[test_sample]))
```

предсказанные значения:

```
In [124]: Y_pred.argmax(axis=1)
Out[124]: array([4, 5, 6, 9, 4], dtype=int64)
```

реальные значения:

```
In [125]: Y_test[test_sample].argmax(axis=1)
Out[125]: array([4, 5, 6, 9, 4], dtype=int64)
```

предсказанные значения в виде матрицы вероятностей:

```
In [126]: Y_pred
Out[126]:
array([[5.9542399e-06, 1.8100386e-09, 5.5844700e-03, 9.6108625e-03, 6.8871397e-01, 1.5016408e-01, 2.4490570e-05, 1.4589421e-01, 1.8510152e-06, 8.9953936e-08],
       [2.2285663e-04, 7.5578096e-04, 1.1629267e-02, 3.2993847e-01, 7.3749710e-05, 6.4566451e-01, 5.8436937e-05, 1.1627958e-02, 6.4288230e-07, 2.8337541e-05],
       [2.0175006e-05, 2.1029808e-05, 7.2457627e-03, 1.6106763e-03, 1.7302675e-02, 3.7940522e-04, 9.7339767e-01, 1.7882046e-05, 7.1474852e-07, 4.1057651e-06],
       [8.1930441e-05, 1.2389393e-04, 1.1717373e-03, 5.5128071e-03, 2.7785455e-03, 6.4186745e-05, 3.9765923e-04, 4.2696856e-04, 1.7411935e-07, 9.8944211e-01],
       [1.4062565e-06, 1.5520934e-07, 5.2866684e-03, 2.0692270e-02, 9.5641917e-01, 2.6243499e-03, 1.4423549e-02, 5.4719596e-04, 1.1895700e-06, 4.0560080e-06]], dtype=float32)
```

точность вашей модели:

```
In [127]: model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
Out[127]: [0.9178167009353637, 0.7298]
#                              ^^^^^^
```

PS я думаю модель можно значительно улучшить воспользовавшись более глубокой архитектурой НС

Answer (score 0):

вот так это работает:

```
 CIFAR10_LABELS_LIST = [
        '1 - airplane', 
        '2 - automobile',
        '3 - bird',
        '4 - cat',
        '5 - deer',
        '6 - dog',
        '7 - frog',
        '8 - horse',
        '9 - ship',
        '10 - truck'
    ]
    CIFAR10_LABELS_LIST = np.array(CIFAR10_LABELS_LIST)


    im= 22 #номер примера картинки из сета

    weights = model.predict(np.array([X_train[im]]))[0]
    print(weights)

    max_weight = weights.max()
    mask  = weights == max_weight

    print(CIFAR10_LABELS_LIST[mask])

    plt.imshow(X_test[im])
```